# stat missing operand error when run from tcl file using exec

Tags: tcl, exec, stat, tclsh

I have the following in `script.tcl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
set disk(free) [exec -- stat -f -c 'scale=3;(%a*%S)/1024/1024/1024' / | bc ]
```

When I execute the script, I get the following output: *(translated from Hungarian)*

```
stat: missing operand
For more information execute the „stat --help” command.
    while executing
"exec -- stat -f -c 'scale=3"
    invoked from within
"set disk(free) [exec -- stat -f -c 'scale=3;(%a*%S)/1024/1024/1024' / | bc ]"
    (file "~/script.tcl" line 2)
```

What am I doing wrong? Running the command on it's own works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to brace your expressions instead of single quotes.

```
% exec stat -f -c {scale=3;(%a*%S)/1024/1024/1024} / | bc
137.916
%
```